# Can I use jquery to blank textarea fields or ajax like input boxes?

Tags: jquery, textarea, onblur, onfocus

I always use this snippet in my work:

```
<input type="text" onblur="if (this.value=='') { this.value='your email'; }" onfocus="if (this.value == 'your email') { this.value=''; }" value="your email" />
```

Basically it will show a text box with "your email" as the value, when the clicks the text input box - the value becomes blank.. thus they type their email.. if they don't type an email it will reset back to the "your email".

I want to do this or similar with textarea and convert it to jQuery (also the above code in jQuery)?

```
<textarea name="msg">Message:</textarea><br />
```

Comment: Side note, when creating email inputs, set the type as `type="email"`. All browsers will default to type text when they don't recognize it (even IE6!) and newer browsers (iPhone/android) will provide better input options, ie.keyboard with an @ sign. WIN-WIN!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to do the trick:

Will work for both inputs and textareas -- Whatever default you set for each will persist. Use as is.

See Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/leifparker/DvqYU/2/

(This pulls and stores the default value in a data attribute)

**HTML**

```
<textarea>I love bananas ..</textarea>
<textarea>How about you?</textarea>
<input type="text" value="Time for a bath ..">
<input type="text" value=".. because I smell">
```

**JS**

```
$('textarea, input[type=text]')
    .each(function(){ 
        $(this).data('defaultText', $(this).val());
    })
    .focus(function(){
        if ($(this).val()==$(this).data('defaultText')) $(this).val('');
    })
    .blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val()=='') $(this).val($(this).data('defaultText'));
    });
```

---

**EDIT:**

An alternative brought up by ANeves, and which makes use of the HTML5 *placeholder* attribute is below. If you don't care about old browsers, you can use the *placeholder* HTML on its own (and it works natively, with results similar to the JS above), or otherwise, as below, you'll need to add a JS fallback.

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/leifparker/DvqYU/14/

**HTML**

```
<textarea placeholder="A few words about yourself"></textarea>
<textarea placeholder=".. and a few more about your mangy cat."></textarea>
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Awesome City">
<input type="email" placeholder="rickastin@youjustgot.com">
```

**JS**

```
function hasPlaceholderSupport() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  return ('placeholder' in input);
}

if (!hasPlaceholderSupport()){
    $('textarea, input[type=text], input[type=email]')
        .each(function(){
            if ($(this).val()=='') $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
        })
        .focus(function(){
            if ($(this).val()==$(this).attr('placeholder')) $(this).val('');
        })
        .blur(function(){
            if ($(this).val()=='') $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
        });
}
```

Comment: @leifparker: I suggest using HTML5`s `placeholder` attribute instead. Would you be so kind as to update the answer? `<input type="email" name="address" placeholder="john@example.net">`, and `$('textarea[placeholder], input[type=text][placeholder]').each()` : consult http://developers.whatwg.org/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-placeholder

Comment: @ANeves Isn't `$('textarea[placeholder], input[type=text][placeholder]').each()` unnecessary? Wouldn't we rather leave it up to the native HTML5 _placeholder_, but add a fallback conditional that implements the above answer if they are using an older browser?

Comment: Yes, I agree completely; new browsers would show the feature and outdated ones would not = progressive enhancement. But then it would be quite a bit of work for you to edit.

Comment: @ANeves Would you agree that this fiddle is the best of both worlds? - http://jsfiddle.net/leifparker/DvqYU/13/ - I'll update the answer if so.

Comment: Please: your answer, your call. `:)` But I agree wholeheartedly. (`return ('placeholder' in input);`? Wow!) If anything, I would add an if on the `.each` to only assign to `val` if the value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use native html attribute `title` to specify the mask text, and then apply following script:

html

```
<input type="text" value="your email" title="your email" /> 
<input type="text" value="your name" title="your name" /> 
<textarea title="your description">your description</textarea>
```

JS

```
$('input[type=text], textarea').focus(function() {
    var $ctrl = $(this);
    var title = $ctrl.attr('title');
    $ctrl.removeClass('mask');
    if ($ctrl.val()== title) { 
      $ctrl.val(''); 
    }
}).blur(function() {
    var $ctrl = $(this);
    if ($ctrl.val().length == 0) { 
        var title = $ctrl.attr('title');
        $ctrl.val(title); 
        $ctrl.addClass('mask');
    }
});
```

And in this case you will need only to provide titles to the controls.

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/pJrG9/7/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [data attributes](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) for a generic solution that would apply to textareas and input boxes -

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="msg" data-notext="text here">Message:</textarea><br />
<input id="email" type="text" data-notext="email here"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("textarea, input[type=text]").bind('focus blur', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val($(this).data('notext'));
})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/3jwtA/

Answer (score 0):

i think you are referring to Placeholder like this:

http://andrew-jones.com/jquery-placeholder-plugin/

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it, hope it helps.

HTML

```
  <input type="text" value="Enter your email:" />   
  <textarea>Message:< /textarea>
```

SCRIPT

```
    $("input[type=text]").focus(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "Enter your email:") $(this).val("");       
    }).blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "") $(this).val("Enter your email:");       
    });  

    $("textarea").focus(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "Message:") $(this).val("");        
    }).blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "") $(this).val("Message:");        
    });
```