# Change value of input/text on blur/focus

Tags: jquery, html

i've got another problem. i guess it's just a stupid mistake, but i just don't get it. so maybe you can help me.
I've got a few text input fields with a "default"-value. onClick in the field the value disappers and the user can insert the data. on blur the "default"-value should appear again, if the field is empty.
This works only, if i klick to the field an blur instantly. if i write something to the box, blur, and focus it again and delete all text and blur, it doesn't work anymore.

the jquery-code is as following:

Here's a fiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7jt/
that's my focus-function. the rest of the code is in the fiddle

```
    $(document).on('focus', '.insert_adresse', function() {
           // $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
            $(this).attr('value', '');
        });
```

Comment: any specific reason for not using `placeholder` ?

Comment: The JSFiddle seems working to me, I'm using Chrome.

Comment: @abhitalks Not working on every browser ?

Comment: Why `.attr` instead of `.val`?

Comment: the jsfiddle works only, if you focus the textfield and blur it without writing anything. if you write something an blur the written text stays there. if you focus again and delete everything and blur again, the default value doesn't get filled in.

Comment: is there any advantage of val()? and how would you solve this with placeholders? i'm pretty new to all this stuff

Comment: `attr` literally changes an attribute. Not all browsers react to attribute changes in the same way. Setting `.val` ensures the actual literal value of the object is updated.

Comment: placeholder="your text here" does exactly what you are trying to do, but its markup. There really isn't much need to use jQuery for this.

Comment: thanks for the hint with "placeholder". never heard of it before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/xQ7jt/3/

Try using markup for this instead. This is also a browser compatibility friendly alternative. `placeholder="Your text here..."` will save you some time.

```
<input type="text" id="input_text_hhnr" class="insert_adresse" name="hhnr" placeholder="Hausnummer" />
```

Comment: To add support for placeholder to older browsers, you can check this answer to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557801/can-i-use-jquery-to-blank-textarea-fields-or-ajax-like-input-boxes/7557994#7557994 (graceful degradation!)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Global variable to store the default values for you, so first you foreach all the input and you store the input id as the Global key, and then in the blur if the input it's empty you replace the value with the Global value ( Default Value ).

Working example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7jt/1/)

```
var global = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').each(function(k,v){
     global[$(v).attr('id')] = $(v).attr('value'); // insert the default value into the Global key with the input ID attr
    });
});

$(document).on('focus', '.insert_adresse', function() {
        // $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        $(this).attr('value', '');
    });

$(document).on('blur', '.insert_adresse', function() {
        // $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
        var value=$(this).val();
        // alert(value);
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        if (value == '') {
          $(this).val(global[$(this).attr('id')]); // get the value with the input id attr
        }
        // alert(value);
        $(this).attr('value', value);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7jt/2/

Please check if this is what you want.

```
$(document).on('focus', '.insert_adresse', function() {
        // $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        $(this).val('');
    });

$(document).on('blur', '.insert_adresse', function() {
        // $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
        var value=$(this).val();
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        if (value.length == 0) {
         // alert('empty');
//          alert(id);
            if (id=='input_text_strasse') {
                value='Straße';
            } else {
                if (id=='input_text_hhnr') {
                    value='Hausnummer';
                } else {
                    if (id=='input_text_hhnrzusatz') {
                        value='Hausnummerzusatz';
                    } else {
                        if (id=='input_text_plz') {
                            value='Postleitzahl';
                        } else {
                            if (id=='input_text_ort') {
                                value='Gemeinde';
                            } else {
                                // alert('here we go');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $(this).val(value);
        }
        // alert(value);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using placeholders (No JS): http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7jt/4/

Here is another example, with much cleaner and simpler JS: http://jsfiddle.net/xQ7jt/5/

```
$(document).on('focus', '.insert_adresse', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val() === $(this).data('default') ? '' : $(this).val());
});

$(document).on('blur', '.insert_adresse', function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val() || $(this).data('default'));
});

$(function () {
    $('.insert_adresse[data-default]').each(function () {
       $(this).val($(this).data('default')); 
    });
});
```